# single mnemonic to create private key with different networks

Tags: blockchain, wallet, wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed

I have both 12 and 24 words, but i can't remember which coin it has.

so shall i try all wallets to find out which has a coin or is there anything i can do practical?

with a 24 words can i create a wallet for most of blockchain networks?

example:
24 words mnemonic-to

- bitcoin wallet
- doge wallet
- ethereum wallet

if there is a library i can also use that then try finding my coins.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Septimus, this site only covers questions about Bitcoin. Someone might help you with the Bitcoin portion of this, but our users might not know about multicoin wallets or care to answer that portion of your question. You might want to ask on a different platform.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.